# Create bootable macOS USB for a non Apple computer

Tags: macos, usb, startup, bootable-disk

I tried several ways to create a bootable macOS USB for a non Apple personal computer. I expected it to work exactly like my bootable Ubuntu USB. macOS bootable USB seems to be working differently. It seems that it only works on Mac. My laptop does not detect my Mac bootable USB as a bootable one on startup.

Is it possible to create a bootable macOS USB, by using Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 dual boot HP laptop, with persistence (optional) so that I can use it by just plugging it in during boot up for building my flutter projects?

Comment: Questions about installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product) are off-topic

Comment: Microsoft offers Windows to Go which can be run from a flash drive on different machines. Many linux distributions offer a live version which also can be run from a flash drive on different machines. Some also offer persistence which allow data to be saved between boots. Apple's macOS can be installed on USB HDD and USB SSD which can be run on different Macs. AFAIK, macOS is not designed to run from a flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

macOS doesn't generally support installing and running on non supported hardware, i.e. non Apple computers. Apple, unlike Microsoft doesn't license its operating system for running on commodity PCs.

> It seems that it only works on Mac. My laptop does not detect my Mac bootable USB as a bootable one on startup.

This is by design. A macOS bootable USB can only boot a compatible Apple Mac computer.

> Is it possible to create a bootable macOS USB for by Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 dual boot HP laptop with persistence (optional) so that I can use it by just plugging it in during boot up for building my flutter projects?

Generally speaking, no.